# Can the Bartering ability be "borrowed" in Divinity: Original Sin 2?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I'm playing Divinity: Original Sin 2 (the "Definitive Edition"). My main character is the Red Prince, and in my party I have Lohse.

I've got **Persuasion** maxed **on my main character** because I'd like to have all possible story options open and I tend to talk with my main character (in addition to playing a few parts where you're temporarily on your own).

Then **Bartering** I'm maxing **on my party member Lohse**. Is that even useful? And if it is, do I need to switch to Lohse when trading items and gold? Do I perhaps even first need to move all items to Lohse's backpack to get full use of her bartering skill?

Or should I go a different route altogether to get the most for my abilities?

PS. Come to think of it, I also open chests with my *main*, but have Lucky Charm on a party member maxed. Should I be looting with the Lucky character instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only Lucky Charm and Loremaster are shared among party members. Every other Civil Ability - Bartering, Persuasion, Telekinesis, Sneaking, and Thievery - will only affect the character who has leveled up that skill.

There are however mods such as [this (for Bartering skill and attitude)](https://www.nexusmods.com/divinityoriginalsin2/mods/249), that enable exactly what you're asking about.

(Note: Since the release of the ["Order and Magic" Gift Bag,](http://forums.larian.com//ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=656607&#Post656607) there is now a 'built-in' equivalent of this mod, accessible through the in-game menu. Enabing 'Hagglers' will mean that all party members share bartering skill and attitude when speaking to NPCs.)

> **Hagglers**: 
>   Tired of forgetting to switch to your 'haggling' character when talking to traders? Now the reputation and skill of your whole party can help you wrangle the best prices!